# Custom SQL in Entity Framework, results are objects of null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to run a custom SQL query in entity framework and bring the results in a specific class. Unfortunately the object inside comes null.

Here is what i tried.

I've declared the class that describes the object.

```
 public class reportReservationReport
    {
        public string Code;
        public string UserName;
    }
```

Then i run the custom query and try to assign to the object.

```
string sqlQuery = "select ReservationPackages.Code, UserName " +
                          "FROM ReservationPackages " ;

        var queryResult = DB.Database.SqlQuery<reportReservationReport>(sqlQuery);
        var query = from pro in queryResult
                    select new reportReservationReport() { Code = pro.Code, UserName = pro.UserName };

        List<reportReservationReport> results = query.ToList();



        string test = results[0].Code;
```

test is coming null.

For the above example, the query returns correct data and ReservationPackages.Code has actual  populated.

Comment: because the object structure returned by your SQL is different than your `reportReservationReport` Model

Comment: In what way ? i have Code in the column name of the results and Code in the class.

Comment: Maybe the type ? Have you try your SQL command in your SQL management platform ?

Comment: Yes, sql command brings normally data. Code is just a nvarchar or string if you prefer.

Comment: your `pro`is already a `Code` so you don't need to do `{Code = pro.Code}` but `{Code = pro}`..?

Comment: If you run that SQL in the database, what does it return? Is the first row null for the code column?

Comment: SQL in database returns data without any nulls. all are populated perfectly.

Comment: Does your class reportReservationReport have another constructor? Also, does the list count reflect the actual rows of the query?

Comment: No other constructor. What do you mean about list count ?

Comment: If query.ToList().Count matches the actual rows from the SQL query, then its a problem with the column names or data types. Try changing the SQL to force the column names: `select ReservationPackages.Code AS Code, UserName AS UserName FROM ReservationPackages`

Comment: I've edited my response, please try placing explicit accessors on the class properties.

Comment: Results were coming yes correct number of rows, but they were null. I found the problem, it was the forgotten {get;set;} in the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your query already projects the `Code` and `UserName`, you need to create a class to read your projection, and use it as a generic parameter of `SqlQuery<T>`:

```
internal sealed class UserInfo {
    string Code { get; set; }
    string UserName { get; set; }
}

string sqlQuery =
    "SELECT ReservationPackages.Code, ReservationPackages.UserName "
+   "FROM ReservationPackages" ;
var queryResult = DB.Database.SqlQuery<UserInfo>(sqlQuery);
var query = queryResult.Select(info => new reportReservationReport {
    Code = info.Code
,   UserName = info.UserName
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to do another select of the result of the query. Try the following:

```
List<reportReservationReport> results = DB.Database.SqlQuery<reportReservationReport>(sqlQuery).ToList();
```

Also make sure that at least the first record has a `NOT NULL` Code value. Without an `ORDER BY` or `WHERE Code IS NOT NULL` (or `PRIMARY KEY`), there is no guarantee that the first record should be `NOT NULL`.

Also, place the Get Set accessors on your class:

```
public class reportReservationReport
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: both results[0].Code and results[0].UserName come null. This is where i was initially.

Comment: definatelly is not null any record